# Swift classes inside Objc framework will it work?

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have one old iOS framework which is written in Objective-c.
I have added some internal classes using swift 5.2. Don't ask why, it just happened.
I want to make this framework available to the public as a binary framework. But now some doubts are eating me.
Are these swift classes adds some limitations or complexity for devs, who will gonna use it?
I mean, if the main app is written in swift 4, will it work with my framework?
Or it was not good idea to mix obj-c and swift in frameworks.
Some explanations is needed here, since my googling didn't help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With the proper `.h` files it should be seamless. It shouldn't be any harder than `import Foundation` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift

Comment: make use of `@objc` keyword in front of `class` and `func` whre needed and you should be fine. File size of a framework is another thing. Yes and you need to make sure the unstable final versioning of swift does not make trouble later